# Driver issues with Touch and Battery On Ubuntu 21.04 Installed on Pluto A108 Tablet

Tags: drivers, battery

I recently bought an x86 Tablet that shipped with windows 10 pro installed, and the OS was so heavy on the tablet that I decided to Install Linux/Android on it.

here are the specs from Neofetch

```
desoky@desoky-tablet-pluto:~$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               desoky@desoky-tablet-pluto 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           -------------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 21.04 x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: PLUTO 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.11.0-16-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 29 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1628 (dpkg), 6 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.1.4 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 800x1280 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 3.38.4 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel Atom x5-Z8300 (4) @ 1.840GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 1767MiB / 3848MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

In case you are wondering why I couldn't just post the manufacture and model number, it's actually because they don't really exist and the real specs of the device I got differs a lot from the most similar one I could find on the internet. However, if you are still interested here is a picture from the box I received it in:

[image: Pluto A108 box PLTA-1002]

Here are the hw-probe log : https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=b95391e679

You can ask me for any report and I reply with the log as soon as possible.

After installing Linux/Androidx86 I found out that the touch driver is not working and the battery was not charging.

First I want to confirm that upon restarting to Windows again the touch driver started working just fine and also the battery charging without any issues, but so far I'm having troubles making them work on any Linux distro.

I have tried on the following kernels:

```
Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 - Linux desoky-tablet-pluto 5.14.9-051409-generic #202109300934 SMP Thu Sep 30 09:39:33 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

WIP : I will try to keep it updated after testing.

When I went back to a fresh install of windows everything was working fine however not out of the box, but rather I had to use a specific driver backup they created for me using "Driver Magician" can provide this backup if you want just let me know.

Anyway, I have tried taking a look into dmesg log from Ubuntu 21.04 and found out weird stuff regarding the touch driver, I will post it here so you can take a look.

Here is the `dmesg` log: https://pastebin.com/BH4WzMht

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to hardware and I can only follow clear instructions so hopefully, you can give more details to what I should do next so I can provide all the information you guys might need.

I'll be checking this question regularly.

Comment: Right off the bat I see you do not have the recommend minimum memory for Ubuntu 21.04  It requires 4 gig. You may want to try a lighter version like xubuntu or kubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1173436) to add more information about the device manufacturer and the model name.

Comment: Ubuntu Touch is a different OS to Ubuntu (Desktop); it's an OS designed for phones/tablets, is based currently on an older Ubuntu system (16.04 with work progressing on the move to 20.04). You mention 20.04 & 21.04 but without specifics as to hardware stack choice you made with 20.04 (if it was 20.04.3 Desktop using HWE kernel stack option; you've have been using the same identical stack to 21.04 so the same results could have been predicted - but you weren't specific as to what 20.04 system you tried..)  The off-topic OSes you mention would also be more useful if you were specific on versions

Comment: @David the device has 4GB of DDR3 Memory and it's running the OS fine it's just the driver issues, not out of memory issues.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi This is a weird subject as the device is not official aka the model number and the manufacture doesn't really exist, but I will try my best to put extra details.

Comment: @guiverc I will edit my post with all the versions clearly again and thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You were most specific on the off-topic stuff (eg. the daily), but didn't mention which 20.04 ISO (desktop? server? 20.04 or 20.04.1 (5.4 kernel) 20.04.2 (5.8 kernel), 20.04.3 (5.11 kernel) etc.. The ISO dictates which kernel stack you've selected (GA default to server, HWE for desktop (& flavors if 20.04.2 or later used)... etc.  Was the 20.04 LTS using HWE & thus the identical stack to your tried 21.04? of a different stack??  We can't tell without specific details (and whilst I know Ubuntu defaults from ISO, it's better if you provide that comparison for non-Ubuntu's from your testing)

Comment: ie. Ubuntu 21.04 uses the 5.11 kernel stack; that same stack is provided with Ubuntu 20.04.3 Desktop installs; but you weren't specific as to what 20.04 media you tried...  Was it media with 5.4 kernel? 5.8? or media that upgraded from initially 5.4 to 5.11?  Without specific details (just generic 20.04) we cannot know what ISO was used, what kernel stack was installed & what it upgrades to (which maybe no change if GA installation media was used, or changed if HWE was used)....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130153/discussion-between-randomlight-and-guiverc).

Comment: I use a Ubuntu SSO (signon) to access this site, however chat requires a Stack Exchange signon be used; so if it was me you're after (in chat), I can't without logging into stack exchange (which I don't with this browser).

Comment: @guiverc so If I understood you correctly I should be reporting versions like this

Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 Kernel 5.11.0-16-generic (x86_64) Correct ?

Comment: for 21.04 there is only the 5.11 kernel (no stack choices exist for non-LTS), however you also mentioned a LTS release (20.04) where two kernel stack choices exist (GA or 5.4 without change for the life of the product) or HWE (5.4 at start too, but upgraded to 20.10's 5.8 kernel at 20.04.2, then 21.04's 5.11 kernel at 20.04.3, then to 5.13 at 20.04.4 etc).. Server & Desktop have different defaults (*flavors* vary on the point level used to install; 20.04 & 20.04.1 use GA, 20.04.2 & later default HWE) so installation media used tells what I was asking. Driver == kernel modules so kernel matters

Comment: @RandomLight In case you are confused, please edit the post and add the kernel version of Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04 (which you can find with the command `uname -a`). You can remove information about PopOS, Mint and Elementary, as they are not supported on this site.